# C++ code using Boost libraries terminated with exit value -1 (What does that mean?)

Tags: c++11, boost, websocket, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to launch a cpp code which uses boost libraries to connect to a webserver (echo.websocket.org). I have successfully compile the code with 0 errors and 0 warnings.

```
//
// Copyright (c) 2016-2017 Vinnie Falco (vinnie dot falco at gmail dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See 
accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
// Official repository: https://github.com/boostorg/beast
//

//------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
//
// Example: WebSocket client, synchronous
//
//------------------------------------------------------------------------        
//[example_websocket_client

#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from 
<boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
using namespace std;

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout <<"Reached "<< endl;
    std::cout <<"Reached "<< argv[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Reached "<< argv[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Reached "<< argv[3] << std::endl;

 try
{
    // Check command line arguments.
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        std::cerr <<
            "Usage: websocket-client-sync <host> <port> <text>\n" <<
            "Example:\n" <<
            "    websocket-client-sync echo.websocket.org 80 \"Hello, world!\"\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto const host = argv[1];
    auto const port = argv[2];
    auto const text = argv[3];

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // These objects perform our I/O
    tcp::resolver resolver{ioc};
    websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{ioc};

    // Look up the domain name
    auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

    // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
    net::connect(ws.next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end());

    // Perform the websocket handshake
    ws.handshake(host, "/");

    // Send the message
    ws.write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));

    // This buffer will hold the incoming message
    beast::multi_buffer buffer;

    // Read a message into our buffer
    ws.read(buffer);

    // Close the WebSocket connection
    ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal);

    // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully

    // The buffers() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
    std::cout << beast::buffers(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
}
catch(std::exception const& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have added couts at the first line of the main, but even those are not getting printed on the console. I have tried excluding them but still the same result. I am not sure what does  **(exit value:-1)** means and how to go forward?

Console output after Build successfull:

> 19:03:28 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project BoostWebSocket ****
>   make all 
>   Building file: ../src/BoostWebSocket.cpp
>   Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
>   g++ -I/usr/local/lib/include -O0 -g3 -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"src/BoostWebSocket.d" -MT"src/BoostWebSocket.d" -o "src/BoostWebSocket.o" "../src/BoostWebSocket.cpp"
>   Finished building: ../src/BoostWebSocket.cpp
>   Building target: BoostWebSocket
>   Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
>   g++ -L/usr/lib -shared -Wl,-soname=libboost_system -pthread -o "BoostWebSocket"  ./src/BoostWebSocket.o
>   Finished building target: BoostWebSocket 19:03:34 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 5s.963ms)

Console output after pressing RUN is blank 
[(image attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qf4S.png)

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger. For a first guess, you might also want to start with an empty `main()`, make sure there is no error, then add parts of the existing code until the error appears. Furthermore, sending `argv[n]` to `std::cout` without making sure it is present will cause the program to fail if the corresponding parameter has not been passed in the command line.

Comment: Hi @Adrian. I did try that before jumping in here. I have passed 'argv[n]' and tried that with 'std::cout' then I added the try-catch block only to print the values of 'argv[n]' as before and the program misbehaved as above.

Comment: @AdrianW I tried a few more things and starte the project from scratch and found that this error started appearing when I am checking the fPIC checkbox here `C/C++ Build>Settings>Tool Settings>Miscellaneous>Position Independant code(-fPIC)` in **Eclipse IDE**. I am checking this check box to resolve this error `relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was in the linking

I had to change `-soname=libboost_system` to `-lboost_system`